# Local minimum of $\sqrt[x]{n\over v-x+1}$

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to find the local minimum of $\sqrt[x]{n\over v-x+1}$ with respect to $x$. The restrictions on $x$ are that it must be $\le v$ and $\ge 1$. Also, $v$ and $n$ are fixed, and $v<n$.

My try: differentiate the expression, admittedly using WolframAlpha, and set equal to zero; get a long expression, much of which can be divided through by since it can't be zero, due to restrictions on $x$; wind up with the equation ${x \over v-x+1}=\ln(\frac n{v-x+1})$, which I have no idea how to solve.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final equation can be solved using the
[Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) .
MAPLE (another computer algebra system) says the following:
$$ x =
 \left( v+1 \right)  \left( {\it LambertW} \left( -{\frac { \left( v+1
 \right) {e^{-1}}}{n}} \right) +1 \right)  \left( {\it LambertW}
 \left( -{\frac { \left( v+1 \right) {e^{-1}}}{n}} \right)  \right) ^{
-1}
$$
Personally, I'd prefer a numerical solution. The latter can be found with a standard numerical method
for finding zeroes of a function. But then you have to know specific values of $n$ and $v$ .

Comment: If you are interested in such numerical solutions, let me know.

Comment: Depending on the value of the argument $x$, there are very good approximations of $W(x)$. These could be useful for starting a Newton procedure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Indeed, Newton-Raphson is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: What else could we think : Newton or Newton or Newton ? I suppose you are familiar with the approximations of $W(x)$; if it is not the case, it is a fascinating area. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve for $x$ $${x \over v-x+1}=\ln(\frac n{v-x+1})$$ Make a change of variable $$\frac n{v-x+1}=y$$ so $$x=-\frac{n}{y}+v+1$$ and the equation to solve becomes $$-n \log (y)-n+(v+1)y=0$$ Any equation of the form $$A+B z+C \log(D+Ez)=0$$ has a solution in terms of Lambert function. In this specific case, the solution is given by $$y=-\frac{n W\left(-\frac{v+1}{e n}\right)}{v+1}$$ from which the formula already given by  Han de Bruijn.

Comment: That adds some _understanding_ to the answers. Thanks!